# Open installed application from application

Tags: android, opencv

I currently have the OpenCV Color Blob Sample installed on my device. I now have an application with a button. When this button is pressed, I am trying to call the OpenCV Color Blob to open, but I have had no success. This is what I have tried:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public String packge_name = "org.opencv.samples.colorblobdetect";
public String class_name = "ColorBlobDetectionActivity";

Button bt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }

public void launchCall() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packge_name, class_name));
    startActivity(intent);
    }   
      }
```

Then this is what I have for my XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:onClick="launchCall"
        android:text="Call Other App" />

       </RelativeLayout>
```

How can I open the application from my application?

Comment: can you explain your question a little more.

Comment: Hi Yogomurthy, sure I can. I have an application installed on my device called Open CV Color Blob. I am now writing a new application, when you click a button in the new application, this will then launch Open CV Colour Blob. I tried to do it with intents, but to no avail.

Comment: Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(launchIntent);

Comment: for this intent to work you must know the package name of the app otherwise it will not work. If necessary add some permission in your manifest based on debug info

Comment: I now have this:

public void launchCall() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
Intent launchIntent = 
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("org.opencv.samples.colorblobdetect"); 
  
startActivity(launchIntent); 
  }

however, the application force closes :(

Comment: post the error code to  see what is the issue.

Comment: I have esssentially put your code where my method launchCall is, was that correct?Getting force close. However I really do appreciate your help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: yes. inside the button listener you have to add this..

Comment: public void launchCall(View view)  change it like this and also add a finish(); at the end of the method

Comment: 04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2141)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at

Comment: android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)

Comment: 04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: 04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: launchCall
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at java.lang.ClassCache.findMethodByName(ClassCache.java:247)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:962)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2134)
04-09 21:59:42.812: E/AndroidRuntime(14638):  ... 11 more

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: launchCall ------check the spelling in your button and java code, check for capitals and smallletters too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address"); startActivity(launchIntent);